# Unable to add doFirst action to the "tasks" task.Could not find method doFirst() for arguments

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to call `doFirst` action on the **"tasks"** task. Here I mean the task named "tasks" that we see listed under **helper tasks** when we run the command "gradle tasks --all".

**EDIT 1 START**

My **build.gradle** :

```
tasks.doFirst{ println "First executed"}
```

**EDIT 1 END**

It gives me below error :

```
Could not find method doFirst() for arguments [build_3m21dsbdvnnfh1sf7441k5d5v$_run_closure5@2cad909f] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer
```

I tried to find out the type of this task "tasks" by running the command `gradle help --task tasks`

It said the type is `TaskReportTask (org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.TaskReportTask)`

I then navigated to the `TaskReportTask` API documentation. As per the documentation this class inherits the method `doFirst` from class `org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask`. I am confused why this doesn't work if its inhereting the doFirst() method.

Any guidance in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post the part of your script where you try to call `doFirst` method?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I have edited my post to include the build script. That's all I have in my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to call method `doFirst` on property `tasks`, which is in fact `project.tasks` (the  instance of `TaskContainer` of the `Project`, see [Project DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:tasks)), and not the `Task` object named `tasks`.

Use the following instead:

```
project.tasks.getByName("tasks").doFirst {
    println "do something before task [tasks] executes"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @M.Ricciuti. I now realize the mistake. Still in chapter 4 of Gradle In Action book and haven't come across the "TaskContainer". Basically I was misled by the statement of section 4.2.2 : `This is especially useful if you want to execute custom logic for tasks that you
didn’t write yourself. For example, you could add a doFirst action to the compile-
Java task of the Java plugin that checks if the project contains at least one Java
source file`. But you made it crystal clear.